# WebSocket реализация

Tags: java, websocket

Сейчас я разрабатываю сервер  который должен будет держать коннекты (предположим 1000) и каждые 1.5 секунд им всем отсылать сообщение с обновленными конкретными данными. Хотелось бы что-бы отклик был минимальный для пользователей, и процессу этому ничто не мешало (авторизация,выход,обновление данных,достать данные). Логично подумав как можно сократить отклик, я решил все запросы к базе данных кэшировать, что у меня получилось, но я решил пойти дальше, при срабатывании onMessage() с данными пользователя (логин+пароль) я делал запрос в бд и доставал от туда данные, а потом их кэшировал, но сейчас у меня возникла мысль, а что если создать отдельный WebSocket сервер который будет заниматься запросами к бд и предоставлению конкретных данных тому серверу который их запросил. Правильный ли это вариант событий? И сколько я выиграю на нем, или не стоит зацикливаться и все операции входа (достать данные из бд) и выхода (обновить данные бд) пользователя на сервере осуществлять так же как и раньше.

Использую библиотеку - [**TooTallNate**](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)

Comment: Вебсокет выгодно делать, когда вам нужно быстро отсылать данные клиенту  в момент их появления. Т.е. меду посылками может быть 1 - 1000 условных секунд. Если у вас фиксированный период, то тут достаточно ajax + кэш. Плодить сервера нужно только в том случае, если одного недостаточно по производительности

Comment: @sakuraso13 как отдельный сервер - это сильно сказано, библиотеку TooTallNate можно использовать как дополнительный порт для "обычного" сервера. Если потребуется сделать "всё в одном" то можно использовать либы из состава tomcat, ws будет работать через 80 порт. У меня аналогичное работает - вход в портал осуществляется через http ("стандартная авторизация") и происходит привязка ws сессии к сессии http (т.е. без наличия входа по http и получения сессии http, по ws не войти) , а вся остальная работа на страницах по ws.
библиотека TooTallNate очень хорошая, начинал с неё.